# Assign Z value to new coordinates based on interpolated response surface in R

Tags: r, spatial-join, xyz

I've created a response surface of sorts based on interpolated z values (bottom of post).

I'm looking for the most efficient way to assign the respective z value to a new point (actually, a dataset of new points), based on the corresponding lat long (which is what the original grid is based on).

Anyone have a recommendation for a command and/or package I may look up?

The grid is not a shapefile so the spatial joining packages I've seen have not been any use.

[image]

Comment: You might find this interesting http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60527/how-to-extract-values-from-rasters-at-location-of-points-in-r

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much @MichaelMiles-Stimson